# R: Map and retrieve values from 2-dimensional grid based on 2 ranged metrics

Tags: r

So, I have a sample dataframe and a sample grid, what I want to do is to map and retrieve corresponding data from the grid based on the value from the dataframe. Please see below for example. Disclaimer: the data and grid are sample, the names/metric names used are totally for parody purpose.

**Sample Grid**: for clarification,

**L is left open and right closed bracket,** i.e. L000_050 means (0, 50], L080_HI means (80, +].

**D is left closed and right open bracket,** i.e. D178_190 means [178, 190), D190_HI means [190, +).

```
df_grid <- data.frame(
  "Tall/Look" = c("D000_178", "D178_190","D190_HI"),
  "L000_050" = c(66.82, 78.17, 80.47),
  "L050_080" = c(78.37, 80.47, 85.47),
  "L080_HI" = c(85.65, 91.85, 90.54)
)
```

```
> print(df_grid)
  Tall.Look L000_050 L050_080 L080_HI
1  D000_178    66.82    78.37   85.65
2  D178_190    78.17    80.47   91.85
3   D190_HI    80.47    85.47   90.54
```

**Data:**

```
df_name <- data.frame(
  "Name" = c("Liam", "Noah", "William", "James", "Oliver", "Lucas", "Benjamin"),
  "Tall" = c(1.75, 1.80, 1.82,1.69,1.92,1.9,1.85),
  "Look" = c(81.33, 75.78, 60.13, 70.52, 50.91, 85.21, 48.07)
)

print(df_name)
```

```
> print(df_name)
      Name Tall  Look
1     Liam 1.75 81.33
2     Noah 1.80 75.78
3  William 1.82 60.13
4    James 1.69 70.52
5   Oliver 1.92 50.91
6    Lucas 1.90 85.21
7 Benjamin 1.85 48.07
```

**Desired output**: basically I want to map the "Tall" and "Look" metrics from df_name to df_grid and retrieve the grid value and store them in "Point" column, results in the following:

```
> print(df_mapped)
      Name Tall  Look Point
1     Liam 1.75 81.33 85.65
2     Noah 1.80 75.78 80.74
3  William 1.82 60.13 80.74
4    James 1.69 70.52 75.37
5   Oliver 1.92 50.91 80.47
6    Lucas 1.90 85.21 90.54
7 Benjamin 1.85 48.07 78.17
```

So far I have been searching online all over for this, I found find_interval, match, and some other material but they don't seem to be designed for 2-dimensional mapping. Please extend your help if you can, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes more sense to make df_grid a matrix. Then you assign the labels to your values in df_name using cut, with labels specified as the rownames or column names of the lookup matrix. After that it's a matter of plugging in the values..

```
# make you df_grid a matrix instead
mat_grid <- rbind(
   c(66.82, 78.17, 80.47),
   c(78.37, 80.47, 85.47),
   c(85.65, 91.85, 90.54)
   )
colnames(mat_grid)=c("D000_178", "D178_190","D190_HI")
rownames(mat_grid)=c("L000_050", "L050_080","L080_HI")

# we assign the labels to Look values
l1 <- cut(df_name$Look,
breaks=c(0,50,80,+Inf),labels=rownames(mat_grid),right=FALSE)
# we assign the labels to Tall values
l2 <- cut(df_name$Tall,
breaks=c(0,1.78,1.90,+Inf),labels=colnames(mat_grid),right=FALSE)
# we call out each mapped values
# might be a faster way to do this without sapply-ing..
# from http://eamoncaddigan.net/r/programming/2015/10/22/indexing-matrices/
df_name$Point = mat_grid[cbind(as.character(l1),as.character(l2))]
```

Comment: Wow this is great, before seeing your answer I didn't know the function cut existed and that I can call value from a matrix with another matrix (I'm not sure what I described correctly reflect what it really is but I meant the last line). I will definitely try to incorporate this into my code. In the meantime, I have also come up with a solution using SQL and dplyr merge, similar to the sql approach in the link: http://shashiasrblog.blogspot.com/2014/01/excel-style-vlookup-and-rangelookup-in-r.html. Would you know how fast your approach is compare to using SQL? the dataset is pretty big.

Comment: BTW, is there a way to code in open/close of bracket? i.e. closed bracket on the left and open bracket on the right [178, 190)?

Comment: Hey, yes I never thought about using SQL and that sounds like a good option. Speed wise, I think it depends on how fast cut works? Because the rest of it is essentially calling out the matrix by row / column index. And for open/close, just set right = TRUE in cut.

Comment: Thanks! 2 quick follow up questions if you have a bit more time: 1. The data i have actually have a 2 level factor column, let's say "rich" and "poor", and correspondingly 2 different grids for rich and poor guys. Is there a way/package (dplyr maybe?) to filter the dataset with only one operation (i.e. If rich, map grid 1, else map 2) and map to 2 grids without having to subset the dataset into 2 subsets by rich/poor then map grids separately and then combine again? 2. I don't even know cut existed, is there a quick way to find out which function I need for a given situation?

Comment: 1. If the grids are not too big, maybe put them in a list, e.g G = list(rich=grid1,poor=grid2), then you call the grids by G[["rich"]][x, y]. Dplyr wise, I really don't know a quick way with data frames to do this.

Comment: 2. Honestly I don't know dude.. My mentor showed 'cut' it to me =p. base R functions, you can learn some of them from older R based statistics textbooks.

Comment: Got it, thanks man! Just implemented this method and it works really well.